# dispersing funds from contract to addresses

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-design

I have a contract with some funds in it and I'd like to equally transfer these funds to addresses that are held in an array. For example, 3 ether in the contract would mean that 1 ether go to each address in an array of 3 addresses. How is this exactly done?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.14;

contract RSVP {

    address public Host;
    address[] public rsvpAddresses;
    address[] public checkedInAddresses;

    enum Status {RSVPInProgress, RSVPCheckInOver}
    Status public status;

    constructor() {
        Host = msg.sender;  
    }

    /// Only the Host can call this function
    error OnlyHost();

    modifier onlyHost() {
        if (msg.sender != Host) {
            revert OnlyHost();
        }
        _;
    }

    function rsvp() public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether, "You must pay 1 ether to RSVP");
        rsvpAddresses.push(payable(msg.sender));
    }

    function getBalance() public view onlyHost returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function eventStartCheckIn(address payable guest) public onlyHost {
        for (uint i = 0; i < rsvpAddresses.length; i++) {
            if (guest == rsvpAddresses[i])
            guest.transfer(1 ether);
            checkedInAddresses.push(guest);
        }
    }

    function checkInOver() public onlyHost {
        status = Status.RSVPCheckInOver;
    }

    function disperseRemainingFunds() public onlyHost {
        require(status == Status.RSVPCheckInOver);
        uint disbursement = (address(this).balance / checkedInAddresses.length);
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this.

```
address[] public addressArray;

function distribute() public {
    uint256 arrayLength = addressArray.length;
    uint256 amountToPay = address(this).balance/arrayLength;
    uint256 i;
    for(i =0; i<arrayLength -1; i++ ){
        payable(addressArray[i]).transfer(amountToPay);
    }
    payable(addressArray[arrayLength-1]).transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

We transfer to the last address outside the loop because the integer division returns the floor function of the division which means some funds may still be in the contract but that wont be larger that the number of addresses in wei. So if there where 20 addresses in your array your last address might receive AT THE MOST 19 extra wei.